# AngularJS orderby refining

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I have a table of names starting with a title (Mr, Mrs, etc) and dates stored as strings plus some other data.

I am currently sorting it using

```
<tr dir-paginate="booking in bookingResults | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchPassenger | itemsPerPage: 15">
```

How could I refine my orderBy to sort names excluding the title (Mr, Mrs, etc) and dates as parsed dates not strings.

What would be best practice here?

**EDIT :** 
I don't want to change the names in the model by the way - I want the format to remain "Mr Foo" and "Mr Bar" but when I sort them I want them to act as if they were just "Foo" and "Bar".

**EDIT EDIT :** 
AngularJS 1.5.6

Comment: So to be clear, all the names you have are "Mr. Blah" or "Mrs. Foo", in other words you're needing to strip the title out of the proper name first?

Comment: Only while sorting, I want the title displayed in the table but not affecting the sort order. And yes, the database entries we get are one string. I can easily strip out the Mr or Mrs in the display, but that doesn't affect the model. Also I'm looking for an approach where I can use different rules of sorting for different columns of the same table. Hope it's slightly clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## getting the right data in the right format

#### title & name

I'd use a regexp to pull the title from the name:

```
var regex = /((Dr\.|Mr\.|Ms\.|Miss|Mrs\.)\s*)/gmi
objName.replace(regex, '')
```

#### date

I'm assuming you're getting either a date object or a standard date string.  If it's the latter, just create a Date object via `new Date(incomingDateString)`.  Then you can call:

```
objDate.getTime() //returns epoch in milliseconds
```

---

## sorting

Some people might dislike this but I hate dirtying up view controllers with methods that NG directives need to use for things like ordering.  Instead, I added some *ng-flagged* properties using `ng-init` on each row item.  Then I can sort based off that.  I didn't do it for the date in the example but you could extrapolate and apply.

#### ng-init w. *ng-flagged* properties

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in vc.listData | orderBy:vc.sortKey track by $index"
    ng-init="row.$name = row.name.replace(vc.regexp, '')">
```

So in other words your objects go from this:

```
{ 
    name:'Mr. Fred Rogers', 
    date:<date-object> 
}
```

to this thanks to `ng-init`:

```
{ 
    name:'Mr. Fred Rogers', 
    date:<date-object>, 
    $name:'Fred Rogers', 
    $date:1466192224091 
}
```

And then via your sorting UI, you can set your `$scope.sortKey` to either `$name` or `$date`.

#### code pen

I made a sample in code pen but I did it with my template which is coffeescript and jade.  You can probably figure out what I'm doing.

pen - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/aZZjgG?editors=1010

Comment: It's a good approach, but I don't want to change the names in the model, I still want it to look like "Mr Blah" and "Mr Foo" but I want them to sort like "Blah" and "Foo". I think I should write a filter or something, I'm looking into it. Thanks for your efforts anyway, I've up-voted this and I'll come back to it and try to implement at least one more time but I don't think this is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You don't have to change the names on the model. Both the *name* & *date* values are the same as they were when you get them from your service.  The ng-init is simply creating new properties on the fly to your models.  This also saves you from having to a) add the comparator method on your controller and b) makes it easier to track issues.

Comment: I tried your codepen again, it wasn't opening this morning for some reason and yeah - now I see it. I marked your answer as the answer. The only thing I'd ask is does your approach effect performance in a negative way? What if the table is large and the user doesn't actually do the sort every time? And I would argue that the comparator solution is better at separating the logic from the view. Otherwise thanks for your effort!

Comment: I'm making an educated guess here since I've not used the comparator feature nor NG1.5.7.  Adding 2 extra properties on each row's model and deferring to simpler sort logic  vs running the objects through a comparator object (esp. one of your answer's complexity), I'd have to bet on my approach as being more performant.  If we're talking a few hundred rows, I don't think you'd notice either way.  If we're talking several thousand, then yea, thinks will be noticeable.  But at that point you'd be paginating them anyway.

Comment: on a separate note, both plunkr and codepen have on occasion just stopped working.  I've tweeted to the plunkr guy and he resolved it within a half day.  May be server issues... who knows.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. Appreciate the input anyway, I already did it my way but I'll keep your answer in mind for future reference. I got confused without the codepen example because I didn't see $name being used elsewhere (switching the sortKey) so I couldn't properly apply it...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some research, I found that the easiest solution is upgrading to **AngularJS version 1.5.7** which introduces the [comparator](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy#using-a-custom-comparator) into the [orderBy](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter.

So I've changed my repeater to use an order by comparator

```
<tr dir-paginate="booking in Results | orderBy:Variable:TrueOrFalse:bookingComparator">
```

***Variable*** is a string which I bound to the table headings so you can change the order by key, **TrueOrFalse** is a boolean which alternates between ascending and descending if you click the table heading and **bookingComparator** is my actual comparator.

My booking comparator looks like this

```
   $scope.bookingComparator = function (a, b) {
        var getTitle = /((Mrs|Mr|Mstr|Miss|Dr)\s*)/g;
        var isDate = /(-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-)/g

        if (getTitle.test(a.value)) {                
            var aName = a.value, bName = b.value;
            return aName.replace(getTitle, '') < bName.replace(getTitle, '') ? -1 : 1
        }

        if (isDate.test(a.value)) {
            var aDate = new Date(a.value), bDate = new Date(b.value);
            return aDate.getTime() < bDate.getTime() ? -1 : 1
        }

        return a.index < b.index ? -1 : 1
    }
```

The comparator is basically a function acting like the javascript [.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

If the value contains a title (Mr, Mrs, etc) it is a name so I strip the titles and compare the actual names regardless of title.

If the variable matches a -Month- pattern, it's a date string and I compare the parsed date objects.

Hope this is helpful to someone, took me a while to figure out. I'm open to suggestions if you think there's a better way of doing this, and feel free to post an answer for people who want to use AngularJS =< 1.5.6